# Geoserver ogcapi plugin jar library not loading

Tags: java, eclipse, geoserver

I am trying to compile two JAR libraries from source in Eclipse: gs-ogcapi-core and gs-ogcapi-features in 2.18 version of Geoserver. I haven't touched any source code yet, but when I run an instance of Geoserver with compiled gs-ogcapi-core, browser returns Error 503 (Service unavailable) on /geoserver/web. When using original gs-ogcapi-core with compiled gs-ogcapi-features /geoserver/web loads correctly, but for /geoserver/ogc/features browser returns error 404.

Please, help me get these JARs running.

[EDIT]
Here's a log from application startup:

```
ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getFeatureHTMLMessageConverter' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-ogcapi-features-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/geoserver/api/features/GetFeatureHTMLMessageConverter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.geoserver.api.FreemarkerTemplateSupport' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:957)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:922)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:576)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just building the jars and throwing in a GeoServer doesn't normally provide all the required dependencies (more libraries needed for the plugins to work).

These community modules are packaged into zips with the dependencies as part of the nightly build process, see https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/

For the ogc-api module, it's still under quite active development, not sure what's inside the 2.17.x series of it, but it's receiving no attention. The version of the module being actively developed is on the master branch, and goes along with GeoServer master.

The wfs-templating module has been recently renamed to features-templating, I believe this one is also targeting the maintenance and stable branches, so 2.17.x and 2.18.x, see here:
https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.17.x/community-latest/
https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.18.x/community-latest/

Again, best to use it with the nightly build of the same day, there is no promise it will work with a release (then again, it might).